# Is there a mysqli_fetch_all() equivalent to return an array of objects?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way to get the entire result set of a mysqli select statement in one call (like `mysqli_fetch_all`) but as an array of objects (instead of an array of associative arrays)? So that I don't have to write this:

```
$arr_objects = [];
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $arr_objects[] = $obj;
}
```